# Why was this question deemed "off-topic?"

Tags: discussion

[This recent question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/248426/how-do-you-remove-this-bathtub-drain-screen) was closed as off-topic. The question asked for help in removing a bathtub strainer, which seems to me a reasonable plumbing-related question.

I agree that the question is not focused, and could have been closed for "needs more focus" or "needs more information" reasons. But how is this plumbing inquiry off-topic on this stack?

Comment: I believe all 3 VTC were based on the custom reason, and the message on top is just a generic message. https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/248426/how-do-you-remove-this-bathtub-drain-screen#comment490457_248426

Comment: @BMitch Thanks.